# Fixing errors in a program I found online, Python

Tags: python

I found this code for a cool looking hangman game that I wanted to try and play. However, when I copied and pasted the code into python so that I could play, I kept receiving errors. I have fixed a few, but I don't know how to fix all of them, because I am not proficient in python programming. Here is the link to the code.

https://github.com/MrT-Productions/CodeExamples/blob/master/Python/Reverse:Evil%20Hangman.py

I fixed the errors to where it will work correctly until I guessed a wrong letter and I received this line:

```
You now have 6 guesses left to play with... Be wiser my friend!
```

Followed by this error:

```
File "C:", line 202, in <module>
    main()
File "C:", line 199, in main
    characterGuess(length, mainDict)
File "C:", line 81, in characterGuess
    print ("There are ", len(gameDict[gameDict.keys()[0]]),"words left")
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

How can I fix this and possibly any other errors after this?

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense - dictionaries aren't guaranteed ordered, so the "first" key wouldn't necessarily be the right one.

Answer (score 3):

The code you're running was written for Python 2, but you're running Python 3.  You could change it to be compatible with Python 3, but if all you want to do is run it, use Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a code-writing service so I won't be fixing the whole thing. But to fix that specific error, do instead:

```
print ("There are ", len(gameDict[list(gameDict.keys())[0]]),"words left")
                                    ^
```

That code was written in Python 2, where `keys()` returned a `list`- in Python 3 it doesn't. All we have to do is make a `list` out of it to make that work.

However, why don't you just run it on Python 2? Or if you are insistent on running it on Python 3, you could always convert it using the [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/2to3.html) tool.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers already mention, this is Python2 code, and you seem to run Python3. Python3 is not backwards compatible. You can try to convert the code on your own, use Python2 to run it, or employ the [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) tool which automates this process.

Comment: How do I employ the 2to3 tool?

Comment: The linked page has all information, do you have a specific question? There are also other 2to3-questions here on SO.